# Partial Match String and full replacement over multiple vectors

Tags: r, list, replace, dplyr

Would like to efficiently replace all partial match strings over a single column by supplying a vector of strings which will be searched (and matched) and also be used as replacement. i.e. for each vector in **df** below, it will partially match for vectors in **vec_string**.  Where matches is found, it will simply replace the entire string with **vec_string**. i.e. turning 'subscriber manager' to 'manager'. By supplying more vectors into **vec_string**, it will search through the whole df until all is complete.

I have started the function, but can't seem to finish it off by replacing the vectors in df with vec_string. Appreciate your help

```
df <- c(
'solicitor'
,'subscriber manager'
,'licensed conveyancer'
,'paralegal'
,'property assistant'
,'secretary'
,'conveyancing paralegal'
,'licensee'
,'conveyancer'
,'principal'
,'assistant'
,'senior conveyancer'
,'law clerk'
,'lawyer'
,'legal practice director'
,'legal secretary'
,'personal assistant'
,'legal assistant'
,'conveyancing clerk')

vec_string <- c('manager','law')

#function to search and replace
replace_func <-
  function(vec,str_vec) {
    repl_str <- list()
    for(i in 1:length(str_vec)) {
      repl_str[[i]] <- grep(str_vec[i],unique(tolower(vec)))
    }
    names(repl_str) <- vec_string
    return(repl_str)
  }

replace_func(df,vec_string)

$`manager`
[1] 2

$law
[1] 13 14
```

As you can see, the function returns a named list with elements to which the replacement will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
res = sapply(df,function(x){
  match = which(sapply(vec_string,function(y) grepl(y,x)))
  if (length(match)){x=vec_string[match[1]]}else{x}
})
res

 [1] "solicitor"               "manager"                 "licensed conveyancer"   
 [4] "paralegal"               "property assistant"      "secretary"              
 [7] "conveyancing paralegal"  "licensee"                "conveyancer"            
[10] "principal"               "assistant"               "senior conveyancer"     
[13] "law"                     "law"                     "legal practice director"
[16] "legal secretary"         "personal assistant"      "legal assistant"        
[19] "conveyancing clerk"
```

We compare each part of `df` with each part of `vec_string`. If there is a match, the `vec_string` part is returned, else it is left as it is. Watch out as if there are more than 1 matches it will keep the first one.